# Django Class Based View acces a variable set in get_context in the get_queryset method

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

If I have a variable I set in the `get_context_data` function, is there a way to access that variable in the `get_queryset` function?

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    coindex_btc_price = requests.get("http://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")

def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
    coindex_btc_price = requests.get("http://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")
```

I don't want to set it two times like that.

Answer (score 3):

I would refactor and create an instance variable that holds the value for you:

```
def __init__(self):
    super(ClassName, self).__init__()
    self.coindex_btc_price = None

def get_coindex_price(self):
    if self.coindex_btc_price is None:
        self.coindex_btc_price = coindex_btc_price = requests.get("http://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")
    return self.coindex_btc_price

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    coindex_btc_price = self.get_coindex_price()

def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
    coindex_btc_price = self.get_coindex_price()
```